# Android unable to reads incorrect jsonObject response

Tags: php, android, json, jsonobjectrequest

```
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);




    sign_in_register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://benedict.reconlasertag.sg/user_control.php", new Response.Listener<String>() {
                //response on sever

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {

                        String user = mEmailView.getText().toString();
                        String pass = mPasswordView.getText().toString();

                        JSONObject jsonObjectzz = null;

                        jsonObjectzz = new JSONObject(response);
                        System.out.println("@@@@@ here is the final jsonobject" + jsonObjectzz);



                        if (jsonObjectzz.names().get(0).equals("success")) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SUCCESS" + jsonObjectzz.getString("success"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                          Login.username = jsonObjectzz.getString("tryme");
                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Welcome.class));


                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error" + jsonObjectzz.getString("error"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Login.useremail = mEmailView.getText().toString();


                }

            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            }) {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    hashMap.put("email", mEmailView.getText().toString());
                    hashMap.put("password", mPasswordView.getText().toString());


                    return hashMap;
                }

            };

            requestQueue.add(request);
        }

    });
```

Above is an extract from my code file for my **LOGIN SYSTEM**.
However, the response from the jsonObject does not match the response given by the PHP URL when tested on POSTMAN. Instead the response showed on my android app shows a result that was used before I updated the new information. It does not make any sense to me.

Next is an extract from the php file

> 

```
class User {

    private $db;
    private $connection;

    function __construct() {
        $this -> db = new DB_Connection();
        $this -> connection = $this->db->getConnection();
    }

    public function does_user_exist($email,$password)
    {
        $query = "Select * from users where email='$email' and password = '$password' ";
        $result = mysqli_query($this->connection, $query);

        //$resultb = mysql_query($query);

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){

            $success = " There are some rows found";

        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
                $r = $row["name"];

            //$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

            $json['success'] = ' Welcome To Earth'. $r;
            $json['tryme'] = $r; 



header('Content-type: application/json');
            echo json_encode($json);
            mysqli_close($this -> connection);
        }
        else{
            $query = "Insert into users (email, password) values ( '$email','$password')";
            $inserted = mysqli_query($this -> connection, $query);
            if($inserted == 1 ){
                $json['success'] = ' Acount created';
            }else{
                $json['error'] = ' Wrong password';
            }

header('Content-type: application/json');
            echo json_encode($json);
            mysqli_close($this->connection);
        }

    }

}


$user = new User();
if(isset($_POST['email'],$_POST['password'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

//  if(isset($_GET["a"])) echo "a is set\n";

    //$name = $_GET['name'];

    if(!empty($email) && !empty($password)){

        $encrypted_password = md5($password);
        $user-> does_user_exist($email,$password);

    }else{
        echo json_encode("you must type both inputs");
    }

}
```

This is the result given when tested with POSTMAN:

> > > {
> > >           "success": " Welcome To EarthBen",
> > >           "tryme": "Ben"
> > >       }

Likewise, the result given for the Android's extract is System.out.println("@@@@@ here is the final jsonobject" + jsonObjectzz) is

> > > > @@@@@ here is the final jsonobject{"success":" Welcome ","tryme":null}

Comment: **Do not use MD5 as a password verifier.** Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use a function such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt`, `passlib.hash` or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force. This is user security and your users deserve secure password protection.

Comment: MD5 and all hashing is not encryption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. There wasn't any problem with the code. It was the app itself.
I reinstalled the app and the response of JSONOBJECT is updated.

I did not experience this problem a year ago. (The last time I touch the app).
It seems that the app did not clear/update the 'cache'.

If anyone knows a better solution towards it. Please let me know.